# How can I increase the chance of receiving review requests? Is it appropriate to contact editors to offer my services as reviewer?

Tags: peer-review, etiquette, career-path

I have a couple of published works, and I have received, so far, three review requests from three different journals. I have decided that reviewing service will help my resume at this stage. How can I increase my chance of receiving review requests from good journals? Is it appropriate to contact an editor and offer my service? Is it appropriate to contact the editors of the same journals that have already asked me to do review, and offer them that I would be willing to do more in future?

Comment: See [How do you earn opportunites to review journals or conference papers?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/how-do-you-earn-opportunites-to-review-journals-or-conference-papers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brian P is entirely correct that this is the sort of service that is valuable to the field, but does not make your CV/resume stand out. Most people view reviewing as a combination of altruism and self-interest in choosing what the field should care about. If, however, you still want to gain more opportunities to review:

1) Ask your collaborators or advisors. Assuming they are more senior, they will probably get more requests than they want to handle, and can suggest you as a potential referee.

2) Do a clear, thorough, and timely job with your reports.

3) If you have reviewed for a journal before or submitted there, you may have a "referee profile" there, which will include keywords for paper topics you are qualified to handle. Make sure these are correct and up-to-date.

4) You can create a public review profile with Publons, which could let editors find you more easily. [I haven't done this, so I can't speak to its effectiveness, but unless you are publicly posting terrible reviews, it probably wouldn't hurt.]

Answer (score 7):

I think being a reviewer can round out your overall scholarly portfolio, but that is definitely not the big ticket item for a CV, especially if you are on or seeking a tenure track position.  If you are an early career investigator, focus on publishing high-quality articles, and then the request for reviews will start to flow.  You can reach out to editors and offer your services.  But, to be frank, I would invest your time in producing, rather than reviewing, scholarly works.